# Nerd font icon is pulled right, and gedit cursor changes to reflect some difference with the icon?

Tags: fonts, gedit

I am using a patched nerd font, [SauceCodePro](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/SourceCodePro).

I have used the [cheat sheet](https://www.nerdfonts.com/cheat-sheet) to copy some icons and paste them into an editor.

For example, I copied the icon for `nf-mdi-yelp`, and when pasted into gedit, it appears as a single character in the first column (as expected).

However, when doing the same for `nf-mdi-yin_yang`, when I paste it it appears in the last column (ie: as if the text is written right-to-left)

[image: icon pulled right]

Notice in the statusbar it says my cursor position is line 2, column 1, but column 1 is all the way to the right.

Interestingly, if I add the yin-yang icon on the same line as the yelp icon, it is "pulled" left.

[image: icon pulled left]

Also interestingly, if I move my cursor to before the yin-yang icon, the gedit cursor changes, displaying a double line, one on either side of the icon, with arrows pointing inward.

[image: weird cursor]

My google-fu is too poor to find anything online to tell me what this cursor in gedit is about.

**Questions:**

- Why is the yin-yang pulled to the right?
- Is it possible to force it left?
- What is the weird double cursor which gedit displays in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Some duckduckgo-fu turned up some possible insight on questions 1 and 2...

The Unicode specification includes a directional specification for each character depending on its script, as noted at https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/web/rtl/. So, some characters are specified as LTR, some as RTL, and some are positioned depending on the adjacent script (e.g. some punctuation).

Since SauceCodePro is a font, the yin-yang "icon" is a character within the font presumably provided at a Unicode unassigned code point. As noted in the answer to the third FAQ question under "Bidirectional Text" at https://www.unicode.org/faq/bidi.html, default values are defined for unassigned code points for all character properties, including the Bidi_Class property specifying a character's direction. It may be that the SauceCodePro developer(s) either inadvertently provided the yin-yang character at an RTL-specified code point or intentionally set the Bidi_Class property for that character to RTL.

Apparently, there is a [Left-To-Right Override character](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/202D) at code point U+202D that should force characters following it LTR. While that character listing includes no description, there's a similar [Right-To-Left Override character](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/202E), at code point U+202E, which includes a description that should be the corollary of the Left-To-Right Override character functionality.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for this!